# What's the best way to sequentially load data in React Next.js from Github repos and show content when ready?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, next.js

I am trying to load data in a Component (say BrowserComponent) that shows a file listing from a server (Github in this case).

I am showing files from multiple repos. So I first get data about the repos themselves, then the file listing and finally the content in each of the files.

I would like to show stuff on the screen as things load - so first the repo items show up, then the listing under each repo and then the content in each file is loaded and each listing item gets a badge saying the content was loaded.

I am trying to figure out how BrowserComponent and stage these loads in a way that follows React patterns.

So far, I can think of and tried two approaches:

1. Maintain some state on the loading process and load progressively when useEffect is triggered. Think state machine.

So looks kind of like:

```
fetchData{
  switch(data.currentState) {
    case LOADING_REPO:
      // load current state on remote repos
      data.repos = ...
      data.currentState = LOADING_LIST
      data.currentRepo = 0;
      data.currentFile = 0;
      break;
    case LOADING_DATA:
      data.repos[data.currentRepo].files[data.currentFile] = ...
      data.currentFile++;
      ...
  }
  setData(data); --> this triggers another update
}
```

This seems to work ok but I feel I'm breaking some patterns (but not sure) and feels 'ugly'.

2. Break things down into tiny components:

- BrowserComponent: This is the overall component. It knows which repos and creates BrowserRepoItem
- BrowserRepoItem: This is a group / container for each repo in the browser. This gets the remote state of the repo on component load / update and creates BrowserFileItem instances as its children.
- BrowserFileItem: This is UI for each file item (say a checkbox or a rename button). This loads the file content on component load / update.

This feels less clunky as far as managing state and loading stages but it's using a bunch of derived content and BrowserFileItem is changing state that's way up in BrowserComponent (which has the source of truth used in the rest of the app).

---

I feel #2 is probably more React-y. I've looked at frameworks like useSWR and TanStack useQuery but they only model things for paging and I don't feel this situation is exactly that. Things like useSWRInfinite still require some kind of trigger to load more data but still rely on some kind of paging concept.

Wondering if people have done stuff like this and have found any specific pattern that works / scales well.

Thanks,
Aditya